# Saving from nonlinearity in GAMS

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to overcome a machine allocation problem with time horizon of 5 day. Production plan is hard to catch up, so my objective is to minimize total machines working time spent. Machines uses molds to produce and there are molds for each type of product. If a product is produced at the end of the day and if there will be production later day, total setup needed for that machine should be decreased by one. For this reason,

```
sets
i: mold type 
j:jobs 
k: days 
parameters
x(i,k) ith mold production needed at day k
y(i,j) 1 if ith mold is compatible with jth machine
Decision variable
m(i,j,k) : 1 if ith mold processed in jth machine in day k    0 o/w
b(j,k) setup number of jth machine in day k
```

While computing the setup number for day 1, `b(j,’1’)`, is simply equal to the sum of `m(i,j,k)`.

For computing other days setup number I tried these but these made problem nonlinear and it takes months to solve.
`b(j,'2')=e=sum(i,m(i,j,'2')) - sum(i,m(i,j,'2')*m(i,j,'1'))`

By this way, if mold `i` is produced in both days, there will not be any setup made at second day. In order to restrain multiple setup reduction I put: `sum(i,m(i,j,'2')*m(i,j,'1')) =l= 1`

So, how can I decrease the setup number for a machine if it has used a mold a day before without making the problem nonlinear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to linearize `m(i,j,'2')*m(i,j,'1')`:

```
  Both(i,j) <= m(i,j,'2')
  Both(i,j) <= m(i,j,'1')
  Both(i,j) >= m(i,j,'2')+m(i,j,'1')-1
  Both(i,j) is a binary variable
```

This transformation is done automatically by some solvers.

Note that there are alternative ways to model the start of a run, and often there are things to exploit (depending on the details).